# Firebase Cloud Messaging for iOS: message sent with console fails

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I setup Firebase Cloud Messaging as instructed in their documentation, namely uploading a APNs authentification key to Firebase to establish a connection FCM -> APNs.
[image: APNs auth key upload]
I double-checked the keyId of this key, and the App ID prefix.

I'm able to receive a FCM token in the app with this implementation in my AppDelegate:

```
// MARK: - Firebase Messaging delegate
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {

    var fcmToken: String? {
        return Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

        print("FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        // TODO: Send token to application server (for login / logout)
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
}
```

So that's a good first step. I then tried to send a notification from the Notification Composer in the Firebase console.
My test is straightforward : a title and the FCM token.
[image: Notification Composer]

But then I get an error, and I can't figure out what happens (Firebase doesn't give much detail):
[image: Failure sending notification]

This is weird because I already implemented FCM on another iOS app before (less complex though), and I checked that the settings are consistent.

The only difference is that this app has several targets.

**Am I correct by thinking that if I get a FCM Token, the configuration between APNs and Firebase is correct?**
What else could I try to debug this?

**UPDATE**: I used a curl to send a notification (as explained on this blog entry: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/debugging-firebase-cloud-messaging-on.html), and I got the following response:

> {"multicast_id":5245063881031284671,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}

I will investigate this "MismatchSenderId".

Comment: have you uploaded .p12 file on firebase??

Comment: Yes (actually, I uploaded the APNs Authentication Key which is a .p8 now, it's the method recommended by Firebase)

Answer (score 1):

OK, apparently my GoogleInfo.plist was a bit messed up, so I downloaded it again from Firebase and it works now.